# create custom listener inside an activity and call it from another activity

Tags: java, android

I have a problem in declaring a custom listener inside an activity and not inside a java class.The problem is how can i create it,trigger it and then implement it.The idea is as follows:
My activity detail will be attached to a listener called download. When the user downloads the book the listener will be triggered and then added to an arrayadapter in other activity called for example DownloadedBooksActivity.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code "Not the image of it" with more details to make it easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can store data of DownloadedBooksActivity in a database and then observe changes in it.
As soon as the download complete update the downloaded item in the database and then DownloadedBooksActivity will automatically listen to the changes.
For this you can use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) or [ObjectBox](https://docs.objectbox.io/getting-started).